# Need to check that text appears on a page once and only once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm using RSpec/Capybara for Rails app testing and I need to check that one element in the view appears once and only once.

For example, in the following code, i need to make sure that `task.title` will appear only once in the page. As shown, I can check if it exists or not, but I could not find how to check that it appears only once.

```
task = FactoryGirl.create(:task)
login_as(task.user, :scope => :user)
visit tasks_index_url
expect(page).to have_content task.title
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Capybara's `page.has_content?` (an alias of `page.has_text?`) takes an optional number of times that the text should appear. So you can just change your expectation to be

```
expect(page).to have_content(task.title, count: 1)
```

`has_text?`/`has_content?` has several other options, which don't appear in [the rdoc](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_text?-instance_method) but are documented in [the source](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb) (starting at line 234 of the current version:):

```
# @option options [Integer] :count (nil) Number of times the text should occur
# @option options [Integer] :minimum (nil) Minimum number of times the text should occur
# @option options [Integer] :maximum (nil) Maximum number of times the text should occur
# @option options [Range] :between (nil) Range of times that should contain number of times text occurs
```